# Set device when using gst-launch alsasrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alsa, pulse-audio, gstreamer

As part of my Sphinx setup, I listen to my input device like this:

```
gst-launch alsasrc
```

(Well, the actual command is this: `alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! vader name=vad auto-threshold=true ! pocketsphinx name=asr ! fakesink`, but it's only with the first bit that I'm having problems.)

And that works, it loads in the default sound card. I can also pass this option:

```
gst-launch alsasrc device="default"
```

That does basically the same.

But when I try to pass it any other input device, like:

```
gst-launch alsasrc device="USB Device 0x46d:0x8d7"
```

It complains about the device not existing.

Now, in the `gst-inspect alsasrc` documentation, it says:

```
 device              : ALSA device, as defined in an asound configuration file
                       flags: leesbaar, schrijfbaar
                       String. Default: "default"
```

I was under the impression most pulseaudio installs no longer use these config files.

So, what can I do to select my input device? Is alsasrc maybe even completely deprecated now that pulseaudio is the norm?

Answer (score 6):

Ah, the device notation is not the actual name as in alsamixer, but like this:

```
gst-launch alsasrc device=hw:1
```

Answer (score 0):

On some system such as openwrt, it may be

```
gst-launch alsasrc device=plughw:1,0
```